# Initializing postgres db with sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm writing a command line utility to initialize a postgres database by dropping all tables, creating the postgis extension, then initialize my models.

The extension needs to be created because my models depend on it.

I'd like to know the "Sequelize way" to do this. For example, would I do this in a seeder then call `sequelize db:seed` ?

The SQL looks like this:

```
-- Drop all tables
drop schema public cascade;
create schema public;

-- Add PostGIS support
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Answer (score 0):

// Edit: Rereading your question I see I missed the explicit request for the Sequelize way to do this - the below might be helpful but is probably not relevant.

I have wrestled with this problem in the apps I've built. The simplest solution (below) is a shell script with a JS script for the Sequelize calls. In other apps I use a number of Python classes along with a couple of JS scripts. This is crude, but flexible and it works.

*run.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_NAME="sqpg"
DB_USER="sequelize"
DB_PW="sequelize"
DB_SCHEMA="s00"
export BLUEBIRD_DEBUG=1

sudo -u postgres psql -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS $DB_SCHEMA CASCADE" "$DB_NAME"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE SCHEMA $DB_SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION $DB_USER;" "$DB_NAME"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION \"uuid-ossp\" SCHEMA $DB_SCHEMA;" "$DB_NAME"

node populate-db.js
```

*populate-db.js*:

```
'use strict';

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

sq_options = { /* ... */ };
var sq = new Sequelize('sqpg', 'sequelize', 'sequelize', sq_options);

var models = {
  Foo: sq.define('Foo', {
    /* ... * /
  },
  Bar: sq.define('Bar', {
    /* ... */
  }
};

models.Foo.belongsToMany(models.Bar, { through: 'foo_bar' });
models.Bar.belongsToMany(models.Foo, { through: 'foo_bar' });

sq.sync({ force: true })
.then(a_function_to_create_some_instances)
.then(a_function_to_create_some_more_instances)
.catch(function(err) {
  console.warn('Rejected promise: ' + err);
  console.warn(err.stack);
})
.finally(function() {
  sq.close();
})
```